# Overwriting an interface pointer value

Tags: pointers, go, struct, interface

I made an interface meant to do basic math with struct values. The interface's math functions always update the values of the struct's pointer.

My problem is that at some point, I want to overwrite the value to the initial value but I only have the interface to work with. Because it is a pointer interface (not 100% sure if this is what people call it), I am unable to "clone" the initial value of the struct in order to overwrite later.

Please also note I'm trying my best to avoid reflection.

Here is my code. Will probably make a lot more sense than me trying to explain it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type mather interface {
    add(mather) mather
    sub(mather) mather
}

type float struct {
    value float64
}

func (f *float) add(m mather) mather {
    f.value += m.(*float).value
    return f
}

func (f *float) sub(m mather) mather {
    f.value -= m.(*float).value
    return f
}

func (f *float) get() interface{} {
    return *f
}

func main() {
    var a, b, c mather

    a = &float{2} // this could be any time. approximitly 10 possible types
    b = &float{7} // this could be any time. approximitly 10 possible types

    // float can't be used again below, only mather

    c = a

    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)
    fmt.Println()

    // a's math
    doMath(a)

    // now math is done, we need to reset the value from before the math was done
    // set *a equal to *c. (a == &float{2})
    resetMath(a, c)

    // b's math
    doMath(b)

    // now math is done, we need to reset the value from before the math was done
    // set *b equal to *c. (b == &float{7})
    resetMath(b, c)

    fmt.Println(a)
    fmt.Println(b)

}

func doMath(m mather) {
    m.add(&float{3})
}

func resetMath(m mather, r mather) {
    m = r
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/3Szk8uQGy5

Comment: What is the expected output? `6`? An interface is kind of a contract, and interaction with underlying data (it can be a pointer, value, whatever you like...) should be done through *method sets*. So, if you want to take *a clone* of an interface, a kind of `clone() mather` method should be provided. To modify the interface, it should be done through other method, e.g. `set(mather)`, then the modification of underlying data should be done in this `set` method (you may using type assertions etc...).

Comment: @putu yip the expected output should be 6. I figured that making set & clone methods should be made but I'm struggling to define these methods that return the `mather` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `clone` and `set` method in `mather` interface, i.e.:

```
type mather interface {
    add(mather) mather
    sub(mather) mather
    get() interface{}
    clone() mather
    set(v mather)
}
```

The implementation of `get`, `set` and `clone` in `float` type looks like:

```
func (f *float) get() interface{} {
    return f.value
}

func (f *float) clone() mather {
    return &float{f.value}
}

func (f *float) set(v mather) {
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case *float:
        f.value = v.value
    //handle other possible types...
    default:
        //handle unknown types
    }
}
```

See [working example in Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NaORzziSwh). The only complicated parts is `set` in which you should determined the underlying type. Here you can use `type switch` to get underlying type, then assign it to `float`. Similar codes need to be added in the other underlying types (you mention that there are 10 possible types).

Comment: Is there no way around it without type assertion? Sorry I know I'm being a bit difficult. The reason I don't want to do type assertion is because developers will be extending this system with their own types. And updating this system every time a developer adds an type that implements `mather` will be troublesome.

Comment: Yes, that will be troublesome. Depend on the *case*, may be there are simpler solution. For clarification, the `mather` type will only support scalar value? How about complex? Vector/matrix?

Comment: Yip, it will have complex types. Which is the main reason I want it extendable. I do however have a lead on something that I'm experimenting with and so far the early tests are looking promising. Will share if it works out or now.

Comment: This was eventually the foundation of my working solution. I managed to get around the type switch with an addition `zero()` function followed by a `add(mather)` function to set the desired value. Not very proud of it, but works until I have time to rework everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using simple addressing operators *if* you have a reference of the underlying type, which you can get through type assertion if necessary without having to resort to reflection. Once you have a `*float`, it's easy:

```
f := &float{2}

var a, b *float
a = f
b = new(float)
*b = *f        // Assign the value pointed to by f to the value pointed to by b
```

In this case your local vars are now `*float` instead of `mather`, but *at least in your example* that doesn't matter. If it does matter, as noted above, you can use type assertions.

Comment: I didn't think to mention that the local vars has to be `mather`. Where I'm using the code it does't know about the type, only that it implements the `mather` interface. Assuming these are the only two options, I might have re-engineer some of my code?

Comment: Line I put in the answer, you can use type assertion (or a type switch) to do it even if the local var is of an interface type.

Comment: I've updated my code slightly. Hope it might make more sense now... There are a few constraints that I forgot to mention before.